# Short Answers Being Treated as Non-Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

[Two of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33226430/1629243) [my recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193289/1629243) received comments saying that they were not answers, when (IMO) they in fact are. They are rather short, and phrased like questions (try ___, can you __). Should these really be posted as comments, or am I being incorrectly reviewed?

Comment: Note: I just realized the first linked answer misunderstood the question, so I deleted it. However, it still was an answer, not a disguised comment.

Comment: "Try ..." and "Can you ..." are at first glance the start of comments. I'd above all rephrase your answers, and would seriously consider expanding them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, the deleted answer was an answer after changing *Try* (would be a comment) with *Use*. A poor one that would deserve downvotes for not addressing the actual question and being much too terse. The minimum would be to show the full expression using `typeof this...`. But starting with *try* makes it a comment without doubt: it is read as *try this and report*

The other one starts with a question. Here again you are asking something to OP so this part should be in a comment. To make it an answer you should rephrase it (just an example):

> If converting text to images is an option, you could use images instead of text. Then it would be impossible to use Ctrl-F.

It is not really much longer, and no longer asks for OP interaction.

TL/DR: *If this is acceptable that is a solution*  could be an answer (possibly poor if it still need to be elaborated), but *Can you do this* **is** a comment